# Canvas for Rust's Amethyst?

Tags: rust, game-development, amethyst

Is there any possibility to draw primitives on some kind of canvas in Amethyst game engine? Let's say I want to draw pixel points, lines, circles etc? I did not find anything straightforward for that, though I admit that my task can be done with a simple texture of black and white pixel, that can be treated as one-pixel sprites. But that doesn't seem to be a right solution.